# Loading dojo fails in internet explorer 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, dojo, xmlhttprequest, typeerror

It fails after doing this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dojo-release-1.7.2-src/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

throwing an error on the statement (in this version, 1.7.2, it is line 260)

```js
return new XMLHttpRequest();
```

being: "TypeError: Object doesn't support this method or property"

The silly thing is that this line is execute a lot of times (maybe even more than 100) without any problem, and it doesn't seem to be dependent on any variables. Unfortunately, at some point it fails. I swapped the line with:

```js
try{ 
    foo = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    return foo;
} catch(e)  {
    console.log("OUCH, ERROR.");
    console.log(typeof window.XMLHttpRequest);
    console.log(e);
}
```

which outputs:

```js
OUCH ERROR.
object
TypeError: Object doesn't support this method or property
```

I am quite lost, as window.XMLHttpRequest seems to be an object, why can't I 'new' it? Any suggestion on how to debug this would be welcome.

What I find absolutely confusing is that this error only occurs when I go to this page using a link. when I refresh the page using F5, everything works, no errors, nothing.

Moreover, it runs flawless in internet explorer 9, firefox and chrome.

Comment: This sounds a wee bit weird as XMLHttpRequest has been supported by IE since 6 n up. Either your installation of IE is fubar or some glitch in the rendering engine makes dojo loader run before window itself is ready..

Comment: Here is a minimal jsfiddle with your try/catch above. http://jsfiddle.net/pcrager/cjpZj/ What happens when you go there with your IE8 install?

Comment: I have ran it in multiple installations of ie8, ultimately in "Windows XP Mode" of windows 7, which ships with ie6, which I then upgraded to ie8. I have a strong feeling this is a race condition, this is suggested by the different result between opening it by a link or refreshing the page. Although I cannot image int to be a simple race condition, like X not loaded before called, as the statement works lots of times before it throws an error. The fiddle runs  fine in my ie8 install, exactly that's whats freaking me out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Clear cache completely in-browser
2. remove any components you have (activex) which are not native
3. if still issues

   - run xml-validation on your HTML
   - make sure the DOCTYPE is correct
   - check for selfclosing / non-closed tags

Comment: I am not sure why, and if you do, please explain it :) But this seems to be the troubling statement:  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />. It was in the head of the document, removing it fixed the problem.

Comment: at some point i have encountered similar issues in regards to IE and charset being unicode. Try for one, using UpperCase UTF-8 and of course, make sure that all of the contents loaded in are encoded in this charset. See two top results here: https://www.google.com/search?q=meta+http-equiv+content+type+utf8+internet+explorer

Comment: oh, and this is why validation of the XMLDocument is so important btw; if an unsupported setting / mode is selected during `<head>` then browser and JS toolkits goes into quirks-mode which is... Encoumbersome to say the least

Comment: *go into quirks-mode*, anyhow, this is extremely helpful! But the fact that this meta-tag is unsupported doesn't mean it is invalid?

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />` looks quite correct and valid to me.. Allthough, `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` should suffice in major browsers.. If it was my site however, I would put the content-type in the response headers, i.e. for PHP `<? header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"); ?>`

Comment: Thanks! This line was generated using a layout in Zend. It was <?= $this->headMeta() ?> which generated the tag. Maybe my zend-configuration is bad or maybe zend has this as a minor bug. I will contact zf, so they can have a look if they wish.

Comment: splendid, glad to be of assistance :)